# Show that $\triangle ABC$ satisfying $B^2=AC$ and $2b=a+c$ is equilateral

Tags: geometry, functions, inequality, contest-math, analytic-geometry

> A $\triangle ABC$ satisfies the conditions below:
> $$B^2=AC \qquad 2b=a+c$$
> Show that it's an equilateral one, where $a=|BC|$, $b=|AC|$, $c=|AB|$ and $B=\angle ABC$, $A=\angle BAC$, $C=\angle ACB$.

What I have done:

When trying to solve these question, I want to find a solution in all triangles which satisfy $2b=a+c$. It means that point $B$ can be regarded as a point in an ellipse.

Then I try to prove that for all points $B$ in that ellipse, we have $B^2\leq AC$. When proving it I think I can get the equal conditions and then show that $AC=B^2$ if and only if $A=B=C$ or $AC=0$.

Then I meet a terrible problem, meaning that I need to show ($x=A$):

$$
\frac{4-5\cos x}{5-4\cos x}\leq\cos\frac{(2\pi-x)-\sqrt{x(4\pi-3x)}}{2}=-\cos \frac{x+\sqrt{x(4\pi -3x)}}{2}，x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{3}]\\
$$

I have never seen such a hard problem before. I try to prove the inequality by segment amplification and minification, derivative, and many other ways but all failed.

Can you help me or give me some hints on this problems?

Comment: What's the source of this problem? It's not often you see a product of angles.

Comment: It comes from a question in a Chinese website(https://www.zhihu.com/question/444496560), and one of my friends come up it and cannot solve it.

Comment: As one of the answers at that link said, changing the roles of the angles and side lengths (so angles are in AP and side lengths in GP) would result in a much nicer problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming $A\ge C$ without loss of generality. Therefore $A=Br$ and $C=\frac Br$ for some $r\ge1$, by the first equation. From the second equation, note that
\begin{align}
&2b=a+c\\
\implies &\dfrac{2b}{2R} = \dfrac{a}{2R}+\dfrac{c}{2R}\\
\implies &2\sin B = \sin A+\sin C&&(\text{By sine rule})\\
\implies &4\cos\dfrac B2\sin\dfrac B2 = 2\sin\left(\dfrac{A+C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{A-C}{2}\right)\\
\implies &2\sin\dfrac B2=\cos\left(\dfrac{A-C}{2}\right)&&\left(\because\cos\frac B2 = \sin\left(\dfrac{A+C}{2}\right)\right)\\
\implies &2=\dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac{A-C}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\dfrac{A+C}{2}\right)}\\
\implies &3=\cot\left(\dfrac{A}{2}\right)\cot\left(\dfrac{C}{2}\right)&&(\text{By componendo and dividendo})\\
\implies &\tan\left(\frac A2\right)\tan\left(\frac C2\right)=\frac13\\
\implies &\tan\left(\dfrac{Br}{2}\right)\tan\left(\dfrac{B}{2r}\right)=\frac13\tag1\label{1}
\end{align}
Also note that
\begin{align}
&A+B+C=\pi\\
\implies &Br+B+\dfrac Br=\pi\\
\implies &B = \dfrac{\pi r}{r^2+r+1}\tag2\label{2}
\end{align}
Using \eqref{2} in \eqref{1}, we get,
\begin{equation}
\tan\left(\dfrac{\frac\pi2\times r^2}{r^2+r+1}\right)\tan\left(\dfrac{\frac\pi2}{r^2+r+1}\right)=\frac13
\end{equation}
Now, since LHS is a decreasing function of $r$ for all $r\ge 1$ and equality holds at $r=1$, hence $r=1$ and we're done.

Comment: Could I ask that why the last equation is decreasing for r >=1?

Comment: @PoLomy, That can be proved using calculus. You can try it as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much for the proof. : )